Создание установщика с минимальным размером
На чем пишут маленькие установщики программ? К примеру установщик Firefox весит 364кб и не требует для своего запуска ничего. Если я создам пустое WPF приложение и опубликую его, то на выходе получится файл размером ~149кб. С включенным .Net 8 будет уже ~155мб, что невероятно много само собой.
Можете поделиться на чем я могу написать установщик(поставить .Net8, скачать и распаковать архив с основной программой), чтобы он весил ну максимум 2-3мб и запускался на Win10/11 без установки дополнительных библиотек?
P.S Не знал какие поставить теги

Кхм... Да и малый размер самой программы равен тому, что программа качает с интернета все остальное. Запустите тогда свой сервер, разместите там архив, напишите программу, которая скачает и распакует, вот вам и установщик. А вообще, уменьшение размера = нативное приложение, то есть AOT, пробуйте. Не, ну если хотите прям изврата, то вперед, только смысл, когда нынче 100 условных МБ для человека не особая проблема. Я могу понять GB, ок, но МБ, да еще и временно на диске... Это экономия на спичках.

@EvgeniyZ https://www.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/download/thanks/

Я это к тому, что основной установщик (уверен, что он еще докачивает) весит под теж самые 100мб, и получается так, что вы качаете ярлык, который качает основной установщик, запускает его, тот качает еще что ему надо, и так далее. Если стоит цель в экономии места, то сами думаю понимаете, что это бесполезно и вы тем самым не сохраните его. Аналогично и с экономией времени и трафика, ибо что так вы скачаете "ярлык" в 1мб, который потом скачает все остальное, что вы сразу скачаете 100мб без "посредника". Так что, звучит это все очень сомнительно...

Если вам интересно на чем написан установщик фаерфокса, то откройте VirusTotal и посмотрите. Это будет 7zS.sfx, то есть самораспаковывающийся архив 7Zip. Далее, если вы распакуете его (поменяйте расширение с .exe на .zip), то увидите там файл setup-stub.exe весом уже в 600+ кб, заливаем также на VirusTotal, вкладка DETAILS, там смотрите Magic и DetectItEasy, ну и увидите там Installer: Nullsoft Scriptable Install System, вот и вся магия... Nullsoft если что, написан на C++, нативный язык без "прослойки" в виде фреймворка (привет AOT). "Большой" установщик кстати аналогично)

AOT + код аккуратный.
